# Pie chart at report

Tags: vb.net, charts

I enter Value for W_Clicks 30 and for S_Clicks 70 and i got chart like this.

[image]

I want that same chart to be created on report. I connected the report to database and i have the values from it to be shown. 
How i need to format it ? What should be Data and What Series. If i have two fields like this and i want them to be shown on chart as example above.

I tried like this [image]

### And this is OUTPUT :

[image]

it reads the data from database/table which is S_Clicks = 250 and W_Clisk = 22

Answer (score 0):

You need to add like this on pictre.

Set this expression to field `=Fields!WI.Value` instead of `Count` or `Sum`

[image]